# Authentication with Ember-data 1.0, Devise, and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ember.js, devise, authorization

I have read the following tutorial for implementing Devise + Rails + Ember for user Authentication and Authorization.

**Resources**

*I followed this tutorial* : http://pivotallabs.com/playing-with-ember-js-and-devise/

**ISSUES**

The tutorial that I followed worked well with Ember-data 0.13, but no longer works with Ember-data 1.0 to sign in or register users . Now, when I click the login button, I am getting a POST to /users with the following errors:

1) POST `localhost:3000/users 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

2) Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object

3) If I am on the login form, I can actually create a user in the database. **NOT GOOD!**

In my sign-in form, I have a Login button that maps to a new_sessions controller. The action is as follows: `<div class="button" {{action save}}><span class="btn-text">Login</span></div>`

**EDIT**: I believe the main source of error occurs in the user routes.

Consider the following old code using Ember 0.13:

/routes/users.js

```
App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.createRecord();
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('content', model);
  }
});

App.SessionsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Session.createRecord();
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

In Ember-data 1.0, this route no longer uses the setupController. You can read more here: http://blog.crowdint.com/2013/09/10/upgrading-your-old-ember-js-application.html

The code would look like

/routes/users.js

```
 App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     return this.store.createRecord('user');
  }
});

App.SessionsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('session');
  }
});
```

The SessionNewRoute cannot return a session by creating a record in the store.

**CODE**

**Ember Initializer**:

/initializer/currentUser.js

```
App.initializer({
name: 'currentUser',

  initialize: function(container) {
     var store = container.lookup('store:main');
     var user = App.User.find('current');

     container.lookup('controller:currentUser').set('content', user);
     container.typeInjection('controller', 'currentUser', 'controller:currentUser');
  }
});
```

**Ember ROUTES**

routes/users.js

```
App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('user');
  }
});

App.SessionsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('user');
  }
});

App.SessionsDestroyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   enter: function() {
   var controller = this.modelFor('currentUser');
     controller.set('content', undefined);

App.Session.find('current').then(function(session) {
  session.deleteRecord('user');
  controller.store.commit();
});

  this.transitionTo('index');
  }
});

 $(function() {
   var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
   });
 });`
```

**Rails Session CONTROLLER**

controllers/sessionscontroller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
     user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:session][:email])

     if user && user.valid_password?(params[:session][:password])
       sign_in user
       render json: {
         session: { id: user.id, email: user.email }
       }, status: :created
     else
       render json: {
         errors: {
           email: "invalid email or password"
          }
       }, status: :unprocessable_entity
     end
   end

  def show
    user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out :user
      render json: {}, status: :accepted
    end
  end
```

**EMBER Sessions Controller**

controllers/sessions_new_controller.js

```
App.SessionsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  actions: {

  save: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.content.save().then(function() {
      var userJSON = self.content.getProperties();
      userJSON.id = 'current';
      var object = self.store.load(App.User, userJSON);
      var user = App.User.find('current');

      self.get('controllers.currentUser').set('content', user);
      self.transitionToRoute('colonies');
    });
  },

  cancel: function() {
    this.content.deleteRecord('user');
    this.transitionToRoute('colonies');
    }
  }
});
```

**Ember CurrentUser Controller**

controllers/current_user_controller.js

```
App.CurrentUserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  isSignedIn: function() {
    return this.get('content') && this.get('content').get('isLoaded');
  }.property('content.isLoaded')
});
```

**STORE**

javascripts/store.js

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: '_ams'
});
```

If I delete the adapter '_ams', the Object error no longer persists. If anyone has any comments as to why my sessions/new view is posting to the userscontroller and how to get around this behavior, thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Much has changed since those versions, take a look at Ember CLI and Ember Simple Auth.